# Is there a better way of creating a Tree in Java?

Tags: java, tree, output

I tried to create a Tree that displays this output.

[image]

My first try was this.

```
LinkedTree<Integer> t = new LinkedTree<>(); 

Position<Integer> p = t.addRoot(4);
Position<Integer> p1 = t.addChild(p, 9); 
Position<Integer> p2 = t.addChild(p, 20);
t.addChild(p1, 7);
t.addChild(p1, 10); 

Position<Integer> p3 = t.addChild(p2, 15);
Position<Integer> p4 = t.addChild(p2, 21);
t.addChild(p3, 12);

Position<Integer> p5 = t.addChild(p3, 17);
t.addChild(p5, 19);

Position<Integer> p6 =  t.addChild(p4, 40);
t.addChild(p6, 30);
t.addChild(p6, 45);
```

Is there a more efficient way of creating this Tree?

Comment: What is `LinkedTree` and `Position` class? Where do they come from?

Comment: Probably taken from here: https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci0160/static/files/docs/nds4/net/datastructures/LinkedTree.html , so not really a public API but part of some course.